# Limits, roots, and exponents in an equation

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

i have been fooling around on the [desmos graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and found something that seems interesting. for insatance, if you have $y=x$, then you have a perfectly straight line, as in the limit equation:

$$
\lim_{x\to \infty}
x=y \Rightarrow y=\infty
$$

Then i put in this equaton:

$$y=\sqrt{x^3}$$

and i got another equation that goes to infinity very quickly. but i noticed that if i zoomed in on the point $(1,1)$ the line $y=\sqrt{x^3}$ seemed to be almost the same as $y=x$ this was interesting news. I then put in this:

$$y=\sqrt[3] {x^4}$$

This got even closer to $y=x$. at this point, i kept going to some:

$$y=\sqrt[256] {\left( x^{257}\right)}$$

at this point, i made this limit equation:

$$\lim_{z\to \infty}
y=\sqrt[z]{\left(x^{z+1}\right)}\rightarrow y=x $$

is there any way to prove this without a graph? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, $y(x)= \sqrt{x^3}= x^{3/2}$.  Was that what you meant?  The derivative of that is $y'(x)= (3/2)x^{1/2}$ which, at x= 1, is y'(1)= 3/2.  The **tangent line** to the graph at (1, 1) is y= (3/2)x- 1/2.  That should have been what you saw.  If $y= \sqrt[z]{x^{z+ 1}}= x^{\frac{z+1}{z}}= x^{1+ \frac{1}{z}}$, yes, as z goes to infinity $\frac{1}{z}$ goes to 0 so y goes to x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have rediscovered a way to think about calculus. Any smooth curve will look more and more like a line when you blow it up at a point.

Here's a desmos picture of your curve near the point $(1,1)$. You can see that the approximating line is not $y=x$ but is $y-1 = (3/2)(x-1)$, with slope $3/2$. That's because $3/2$ is the derivative of your smooth curve at that point.

The slope of the curve 
$$
y = x^{(z+1)/z}
$$
at the point $(1,1)$ is $(z+1)/z$, which is indeed close to $1$ when $z$ is large.  When you learn calculus you will be able to make that calculation algebraically, without a graph.

[image]